# Clustering Average depth of table vs partition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

select system$clustering_depth('Table1','(Column1)');

It gives the **average depth** of the **table** according to the specified columns :in my case the value is 17501.1143.Which tells that this table is badly clustered .

select SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION('Table1','(Column1)');

Average **overlap depth of each micro-partition** in the table. : in my case the value is 16033 which tells that the table is badly clustered.

Question :1 The first value is for a **table** (17501.1143)and second value(16033) is for  a **partition** as per the snowflake documentation .

which one we should consider in order to analyse clustering for Table1?

Question :2  Theoretically they both represents the same ?if so ,why each of them has different values?

Answer (score 1):

Question #1: Both.  You want both of those numbers to get as close to 1 as possible for your clustering key.  If you are specifying a column on the table that isn't actually the cluster key, then it'll likely be badly clustered unless things were loaded in order of that column.

Question #2: I highly recommend reading this portion of the Snowflake Documentation to understand the difference between overlap and depth.  It shows a nice illustration.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#clustering-depth